# ECS service keeps deregistering Target Group and start/stop tasks

Tags: containers, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service that is repeatedly starting and stopping a task running on a EC2 (`m5.large`) launch type container. The Events tab says these messages in a loop -

```
service test-service deregistered 1 targets in target-group localhost-localhost-default

service test-service has begun draining connections on 1 tasks.

service test-service deregistered 1 targets in target-group localhost-localhost-default

service test-service has started 2 tasks: task 4e1569b3-a15c-4bac-85f7-396b530113a5 task d5651035-8e3d-48df-b457-d05e5b7be8db.
```

There is nothing more there to help understand what might be going on. When I checked the Target group itself, the instances are not registered anymore to it. I have allocated `memory: 1024` and `cpu: 512` for the task which should be enough.

Is there anything I can do to understand what the problem here is ?

Comment: Do you have some Load balancer configured? Check that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html. Some Health checks maybe finishing your tasks

Comment: @JhonnFrazão - Yes I have a ALB configured with the target group and 2 EC2 instances in it. They show `Unhealthy` to begin with.  I added Cloudwatch monitoring and see this message in the LOGS tab - `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`. I am guessing it is because the container cannot connect to the server. But I do not think that should start/stop the container itself. Or could it ?

Comment: It can and that's how it's supposed to work. If a health check condition cannot be met, and you have your ECS service configured to use ALB health check, then it will terminate containers not passing health checks.

Comment: @marianogg9 I did get this to work. The container ports were not correctly exposed.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. In my case ECS was trying to deploy an old image that was misconfigured. It was just a matter of time before my latest deploy took precedence. In my case, reviewing the logs of the containers is how I figured it out.

Answer (score 13):

On this line,

```
service test-service has started 2 tasks: task 4e1569b3-a15c-4bac-85f7-396b530113a5 task d5651035-8e3d-48df-b457-d05e5b7be8db.
```

Task ID is a hyperlink, when you click that it will take you the page where you can find all the details about that particular task.

Here there is a entry "stopped reason" which will show why was the task stopped.

If it stopped because of health check failures, it will show in events page itself.

Comment: How is `4e1569b3-a15c-4bac-85f7-396b530113a5` a hyperlink? What is an example path for this?